# Show layout on all main layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I set progress dialog main activity, I set the custom_dialog.xml layout on the progress dialog (use custom progress dialog), you show from the picture there is top and bottom area show from main activity, I would the layout or the progress dialog show on all the page or screen like splash activity

[image: 1]

custom_dialog.xml ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/icon" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to solve it by xml or java code?

Comment: are you asking why your progress bar is not showing in your activity?

Comment: "the layout do not show on the all main layout" -- Maybe that is because your other "main layouts" don't have a ProgressBar?

Comment: no, the progress bar is show, show the image above, you see some main contents, I would hide it, I mean I would show progress layout like the splash screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        androud:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/icon"
    />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks :) it work, I remove scaleType from image view because there error (attributes is missing the android namespace) and I added content description :) Thanks

Comment: How to solve this problem in picture in huge screens 
http://dorraq.net/uploads/642016-104136AM-1.jpg